# Vue: How to use an object in component data?

Tags: vue.js, reactive-programming

In some component, I have this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            a: 'a',
            b: {}
        };
    }
}
```

Now, if I do `this.a = 'aa';` somewhere, and I use `this.a` in a computed function, then everything happily updates reactively. If, however, I do `this.b.key = 'bb';` ... then nothing happens. That is, `this.b` is not updated reactively, which makes us sad.

After some testing, it seems that I can trigger reactive updates to `this.b`, but only by assigning `this.b = completelyNewObject;` ... which is awkward.

Furthermore, in this case, `this.b` is not iterable, which makes using it in a computed function rather difficult.

So... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is how vue works, read this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `b.key` does not exist in the initial state of the data object, so Vue was not able to bind to it. The simple solution would be to add a `key` property to your initial object. You can also use `Vue.set` to assign the value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
   return {
      a: {},
      b: {
       key: ''
      },
      c: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
   changeA(){
     this.a.key = Math.random();
    },
    changeB(){
     this.b.key = Math.random();
    },
    changeC(){
     Vue.set(this.c, 'key', Math.random());
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p><button @click="changeA">Change me!</button> <strong>a.key:</strong> {{ a.key }}</p>
  <p><button @click="changeB">Change me!</button> <strong>b.key:</strong> {{ b.key }}</p>
  <p><button @click="changeC">Change me!</button> <strong>c.key:</strong> {{ c.key }}</p>
</div>
```

Notice how both b and c are reactive and update instantaneously, while a is not (it does update if you change b or c thanks to Vue re-rendering the app/component).

Comment: Thanks for that.  We are actually using nuxt, so Vue isn't a thing.  Any idea how this would be done nuxtly?

Comment: I've never used Nuxt, but if you can't get access to the Vue object, your best bet would probably be to use method `b` above, and initialize the object with a `key` property already in it.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a limitation in Vue 2.x, and the possible solutions are using Vue.set or this.$set or Object.assign methods for example

```
this.$set(this.b, 'key', 'value to assign')
```

OR

```
Vue.set(this.b, 'key', 'value to assign')
```

OR

```
this.b= Object.assign({}, this.b, { key: 'value to assign' })
```

Note: this issue is already resolved in Vue 3 but mostly people are still on Vue 2x :)

Comment: Vue 3 is not released yet, only few RFC for **Vue 2.x Next** are available.

Comment: I've seen some projects using vue 3 already. I'll share link to that if I find it now

Comment: Yep, which is pretty much the solution I came up with (i.e., this.b = completelyNewObject;) but... any ideas about the other part of my question? this.b is not iterable. How to access the keys of this object, in a computed funciton?